# Incrementing & Displaying Array When Data Matches Number Range in Column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with a column whose data I want to sort. The column is listed with different numbers. I want to sort the numbers into ranges and count how many times a number appears in the range:

0

1 - 50,000

50,001 - 75,000

75,001 - 100,000

100,000 +

So far, I've created a while loop that loops through the column data and shows a table with all the numbers. Now, I am trying to loop through the row and have it sort the numbers - if it is in a certain range, it should add (increment up 1) to the variable/array for that range. The variable is counting how many times a number appears in that range.

These are my `if` statements that should check if the data in the column is in a range, and add a number to the array (when I add in this piece of code to my script, it goes blank on the browser):

```
    if($credit_limit = 0) {
        $cred0++;
    }

    if($credit_limit >= 1 && $credit_limit <= 50,000) {
        $cred1_50000++;
    }

    if($credit_limit >= 50,001 && $credit_limit <= 75,000) {
        $cred50001_75000++;
    }

    if($credit_limit >= 75,001 && $credit_limit <= 100,000) {
        $cred75001_100000++;
    }

    if($credit_limit > 100,000) {
        $cred_100000++;
    }

    $credit_data = array(
        array('0', $cred0),
        array('1 to 50,000', $cred1_50000),
        array('50,001 to 75,000', $cred50001_75000),
        array('75,001 to 100,000', $cred75001_100000),
        array('100,000', $cred_100000)  
    );
```

I would appreciate any insights as to why my code is showing up blank on the script, and why it is not incrementing up the variables in the array or displaying the count when echoed.

Here is all the code:

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/database_connection.php");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // VARIABLES FOR CREDIT LIMIT RANGES

    $cred0 = 0;
    $cred1_50000 = 0;
    $cred50001_75000 = 0;
    $cred75001_100000 = 0;
    $cred_100000 = 0;

    // QUERY TO GET DATA FROM CREDIT LIMIT COLUMN

    $credit_limit = 'SELECT creditLimit FROM customers ORDER BY customerNumber ASC';
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) 
        or die ('Error querying database');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="classic_cars.css" />
    <style>
        #table11 {
            height: 100px;
        }   
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        require_once("./includes/navigation.php");
    ?>
        <h1>Credit Limit Table</h1>
        <div id="table11">
        <table border= "1"> 
            <tr>
                <td>Credit Limit</td>
            </tr>
        <?php

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $creditLimit = $row['creditLimit'];

                // SHOW COLUMN WITH DATA IN A TABLE

                echo "<tr>
                        <td>$creditLimit</td>
                    </tr>";

                // ++ INCREMENT INTO ARRAY IF VALUE IN COLUMN IS WITHIN CERTAIN RANGE

                    if($credit_limit = 0) {
                        $cred0++;
                    }

                    if($credit_limit >= 1 && $credit_limit <= 50,000) {
                        $cred1_50000++;
                    }

                    if($credit_limit >= 50,001 && $credit_limit <= 75,000) {
                        $cred50001_75000++;
                    }

                    if($credit_limit >= 75,001 && $credit_limit <= 100,000) {
                        $cred75001_100000++;
                    }

                    if($credit_limit > 100,000) {
                        $cred_100000++;
                    }

                    // ARRAY

                    $credit_data = array(
                        array('0', $cred0),
                        array('1 to 50,000', $cred1_50000),
                        array('50,001 to 75,000', $cred50001_75000),
                        array('75,001 to 100,000', $cred75001_100000),
                        array('100,000', $cred_100000)  
                    );

                    // DISPLAY HOW MANY TIMES A NUMBER IN SPECIFIED RANGE SHOWS UP
                    echo $cred0;
                    echo $cred1_50000;
                    echo $cred50001_75000;
                    echo $cred75001_100000;
                    echo $cred_100000;

            } // end while loop
        ?>

    </table>
    <div>



    <?php
        require_once("./includes/footer.php");
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the desired output? You can do the count in MySQL using a case statement if you just want to display the ranges and the occurrences of numbers within the range.

Comment: firstly, you're doing an assignment here `if($credit_limit = 0)` so `$credit_limit` will always equal zero.

Comment: so, do a [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead ^ and then take it from there. Plus, this doesn't help you in your query `or die ('Error querying database');` this does `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))`

Comment: another thing `50,000` etc. make sure you can use that format. If your column is an `int` with `50000` stored in there, well... that'll cause you problems.

Comment: @Fred -ii-  yes, the 50,000 format was causing problems. i changed stripped the commas from the formatting. thanks.

Comment: @Fred -ii- yes the comparison operator for the = 0 was an issue too. I changed it to == and it is evaluating properly. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the commas for your numbers need to be removed.

50,000 to 50000 etc.

You could probably get away with using [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format), but that would be more work for nothing.

You're also assigning `=` instead of comparing `==` here:

```
if($credit_limit = 0)
```

so `$credit_limit` will always evaluate to 0.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making all the job with php loops, why don't you try that mysql does the hard work?
If you have the field "creditLimit" indexed, mysql will fly giving you the answer.

```
 $credit_limit = 'SELECT COUNT(creditLimit) as total FROM customers 
WHERE creditLimit=0';
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) ;
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<br>Number of costumers with credit 0 ".$data['total'];
//---------------------------------------------------------
 $credit_limit = 'SELECT COUNT(creditLimit) as total FROM customers 
WHERE creditLimit>0 and creditLimit<=50000';
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) ;
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<br>Number of costumers >1 and <=50000 ".$data['total'];

//---------------------------------------------------------
 $credit_limit = 'SELECT COUNT(creditLimit) as total FROM customers 
WHERE creditLimit>50000 and creditLimit<=75000';
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) ;
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<br>Number of costumers >50000 and <=75000 ".$data['total'];

//---------------------------------------------------------
 $credit_limit = 'SELECT COUNT(creditLimit) as total FROM customers 
WHERE creditLimit>75000 and creditLimit<=100000';
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) ;
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<br>Number of costumers >75000 and <=100000 ".$data['total'];
//---------------------------------------------------------
 $credit_limit = 'SELECT COUNT(creditLimit) as total FROM customers WHERE creditLimit>100000';
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $credit_limit) ;
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<br>Number of costumers >100000 ".$data['total'];
```

Comment: care to explain your answer a bit more? you've also missed something.

Comment: and this will fail `mysql_fetch_assoc`